# DIY Ambilight project, Raspberry Pi receiving video input

Tags: hdmi, video

So Got myself a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B 4GB RAM. I have also bought a S-100-5 PSU (20A) for lighting a WS2812 addressable light strip.

My overall goal is to create a Responsive AmbiLight for my TV.

[image]
The diagram is my best attempt at representing the setup I wish to achieve.

The problem lies between the HDMI splitter and the Pi. I've since learnt that the HDMI socket is an output only, and that the USB sockets 2.0 or 3.0 can't handle the data transfer from HDMI unless I use an expensive capture card.

So basically. What else can I do to achieve what I want?

Note: the video does not need to be HD quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an HDMI to Composite Video grabber together with an Composite Video to USB 2.0 grabber. The Pi is able to work with the signal from the CV to USB 2.0 grabber, if the chip is supported. If you search on your favourite webshop for "UTV007 USB Video Grabber", you'll find one.

Comment: Thank you, I've seen these. and they are cheaper than a HDMI to CSI-2 board, Also next day delivery. It just seems like a real hacky way to do it. There's plenty of them being sold on amazon. What do those products do that I can't do.

Comment: As you noticed already, there is no way to get the HDMI signal into the pi without additional hardware. Therefore, what these products do and what you can't do is precisely getting the HDMI signal into your pi.

Comment: Yeah, it seems so, I've done all the research I can looking for a better way. this was my last ditch effort of finding a better way to do it. But I've ordered the video grabber and a HDMI to AV converter. Thanks for confirming this with me. :)